# Maven and IBM worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

Is there's a way I can mavenize IBM Worklight adapters build rather than using ANT ? Benefit i get from this is i need not require to install IBM worklight on my build server as well as for development. 
If not maven then do we have any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WL doesn't have maven support. This said, you can integrate ANT tool WL provides in your maven build. You don't need the whole WL installed on your build server, just ANT runtime and ANT tool jar provided by WL. From there on - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/